# Why isn't the AI following the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have written some code and everything works in it besides the AI following the player. I don't know what I did wrong so any help would be gladly appreciated!

```
public class SharkAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;


    public Transform patrolPoints;

    private float waitTime;
    public float startWaitTime;

    public float minX;
    public float maxX;
    public float minY;
    public float maxY;

    public float oldPosition;
    public float newPosition;

    private SpriteRenderer fishes;
    public float eyeSightOfFish;
    public float disToPlayer;

    private Transform player;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        waitTime = startWaitTime;
        patrolPoints.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(minX, maxX), Random.Range(minY, maxY));
        fishes = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
        oldPosition = transform.position.x;
        newPosition = patrolPoints.position.x;
        Debug.Log("Player distance " + disToPlayer);

        //distToPatrolPoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, patrolPoints[whichPoint].transform.position);
        disToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.transform.position);

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, patrolPoints.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (newPosition > oldPosition)
        {
            fishes.flipX = true;
        }
        else { fishes.flipX = false; }

        if(disToPlayer <= eyeSightOfFish)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        else if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, patrolPoints.position) <= 0.2f)
        {
            if (waitTime <= 0)
            {
                patrolPoints.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(minX, maxX), Random.Range(minY, maxY));
                waitTime = startWaitTime;
            }
            else
            {
                waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so im not sure where this is wrong and ive tried a few things but I can't seem to make the ai follow the player.

Comment: Try simplifying your script and just have it follow the player. Once that works try adding back in your patrol behavior.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if your code ever enters the `if(disToPlayer <= eyeSightOfFish)` statement?

Comment: @AlexMyers when I do a debug log and I get with the eyeSight of the fish it tells me true.

Comment: @Motm Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. Did your code enter the if statement I mentioned above when you stepped through with the debugger?

Comment: @AlexMyers bascially I made the debugger log true if I the disToPlayer <= eyeSightOfFish. this was my debug log statement "Debug.Log("Test " + (disToPlayer <= eyeSightOfFish));" and it returns true if I got within  <= the eyeSightOfFish

Comment: First of all, you can define `player` in your start method.
Second, did you gave the `player` the tag `Player`?

Comment: larsB I know but I want it in update so when the player moves it updates. if I have it in the start method it will only get that one position when the game start and yes the player has the tag Player

Comment: Just so you know, a transform is a reference type (the transform belonging to the player), so even if the player moves you will still get its correct position from player.position. You don't need to get the transform every frame.